# Limit scope of external css to only a specific page?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a django project   using  HTML5, and CSS,.

while extending the base.html to other files ,when I load in a new css file, it (obviously) overrides the one I'm using to style the page, and therefore most of the  elements are affected like a tag and others. so is there Limit scope of external css to only a specific file.?
Please tell me some solution i am a beginner  and i am frustrated by this

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you.
That also shows what you have done so far and at which specific problem you are stuck.

Comment: you mean to limit css to a specific template(.html file)?

Comment: you can make a varible name css = 'mycsslink' pass it to the only page in which you need it. also you can use this variable in main base.html so when this page its passes link to base.html  only on your specific page